# Eclipse compilation errors when enabling semantic analysis on SPL classes

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, semantic-analysis

I have a PHP project which I develop with Eclipse. Project is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/elgervb/compact/.

When I enable Semantic Analysis (*Window* -> *Preferences* -> *PHP* -> *Semantic Analysis*), then I get all kinds of compilation errors regarding the Standard PHP Library (SPL).

It seems it cannot find all SPL classes. Error typically shown in the error view:

> The type ArrayObject cannot be resolved    FileRepository.php  /compact/classes/compact/repository/file    line 320    DLTK Problem
>
> The type Closure cannot be resolved    Router.php  /compact/classes/compact/routing    line 33 DLTK Problem
>
> The type \PDO cannot be resolved   AbstractPDORepository.php   /compact/classes/compact/repository/pdo line 41 DLTK Problem

... and many, many more.

I have Zend Eclipse for PHP Developers, version: 3.2.0.
My project has PHP Support. The PHP Language Library is on my build path, that contains the Core API, which has the SPL.php file.

Does anyone know how to resolve this, as I clearly want to use semantic analysis? Does anyone has experienced these problems too?

Comment: Try to reduce your code as much as possible that still produces the error. Then post that code here in your question

Comment: Tnx Christiaan, but I found the reason why this was happening. Please see my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. When I enabled PHP Core Facet and PHP Facet on my project it worked.

Goto project -> properties -> Project Facets and enable both facets..

Answer (score 1):

"Project > Clean" Works me works for me when Facets are enabled, but there is an error.